# OpenSSL installed with Homebrew on macOS 10.15.6 appears to be stuck at version @1.1, getting the latest instead?

Tags: installation, openssl, homebrew, macos-catalina, version

I'm using macOS 10.15.6 Catalina and Homebrew (latest version, 2.5.1). When I do `brew list` I notice there is `openssl@1.1` in my list of installed formulae.

I can't recall if I ever installed `openssl` manually or that it came along with another formula, but I certainly never explicitly picked the `@1.1` version myself.

When I do `openssl version` it says `LibreSSL 2.8.3`.

When I do `brew install openssl` it says:

> Warning: openssl@1.1 1.1.1g is already installed and up-to-date
> To reinstall 1.1.1g, run `brew reinstall openssl@1.1`

Instead I tried `brew install libressl`. That installs OK, but when I now do `openssl version` it still says `LibreSSL 2.8.3`.

However if I do `/usr/local/opt/libressl/bin/openssl version` it says `LibreSSL 3.1.4` which seems more up to date. So now apparently two versions are installed, but the 'default' one is still the older version.

Two questions:

1. I just want to use the latest openssl (or libressl). When I run `openssl` I want it to invoke the latest version available. Can I or should I somehow get rid of the `@1.1` version and just install the latest openssl instead? Or install libressl as I did, but then I want that to be the default, not the old one.
2. Considering that the @1.1 version will probably be there for a reason, may that imply that some other software depending on that specific version will no longer work? This kinda feels crappy, for example what if I happen to have two pieces of software that each depend on a different specific version. Can I instruct software depending older openssl versions to use a specific path for that older version, while keeping just `openssl` (without explicit path) to be the latest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacOS includes an older version of `openssl`, that's what's by default in the path, and that's the one you'll see (try `which openssl` to see which one gets picked up on your computer).

Homebrew installs `openssl@1.1` into `/opt`, which means you need to explicitly call it from there, and if you want to link other programs you compile to it, you need to set library paths etc.

Same for libressl.

> I just want to use the latest openssl (or libressl).

The binary, I assume? One way to do that is to add your own `$HOME/bin` directory in front of your `PATH` (something I recommend anyway) in your shell, and make a shell script `openssl` in there that calls the version you want to use. When you do it that way, you won't mess up anything else.

> may that imply that some other software depending on that specific version will no longer work?

Exactly. That's why you shouldn't replace the one that comes with MacOS, for example.

> Can I instruct software depending older openssl versions to use a specific path for that older version,

If you do it the other way round (have a different PATH in your terminal), then anything you call from outside the terminal isn't going to break, for starters.

---

To answer questions in the comment:

1. I have a `~/.profile` with

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

   in it.
2. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811345/how-to-pass-all-arguments-passed-to-my-bash-script-to-a-function-of-mine). That is: Create a file `~/bin/openssl` with

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   exec /usr/local/opt/libressl/bin/openssl "$@"
   ```

in it. Don't forget to `chmod a+x ~/bin/openssl`.

Environment will get passed, redirections will apply. Wildcards will be resolved on first call, but passed on in resolved form.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to try that, but I'm running into two new questions: 1. [how to properly add $HOME/bin in front of my PATH ?](https://superuser.com/questions/1587113/shell-environments-prepend-a-path-to-my-path-environment-variable-in-both-bash) And 2. what would my $HOME/bin/openssl script look like to make sure I literally pass on any random set of arguments (possibly also including environment variables or wildcards) or stdin et cetera to the binary I'm calling?

Comment: See edit for answers.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, why the `exec` in the `~/bin/openssl` script? (it also seems to work without `exec`)

Comment: See `man bash`. `exec` causes the called command to replace the shell script process, so you don't use up resources unnecessarily while the real `openssl` is running.